# Background-color doesn't stretch to fit the div using bootstrap on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that I'm working on and have used Twitter Bootstrap 2.3. It happens in a few places but for example in the footer, the background color does not stretch to fit the div on an iPhone/iPad.

Can anyone help me please? It's driving me insane!

The website is http://goo.gl/jZotaj

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: You have 651 errors within your CSS alone. Use W3C CSS validator as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I have entered your site.
At first glance, the site has 46 warnings and 3 errors.
Look at errors at css (open this on chrome, i.e - Tools for developers).
Most of the warnings related to css, and I think you forgot "{" or something.

Check that out. You should have (also for best practice) zero warnings & zero errors.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because your `span4` divs in the footer are floated, but nothing else is. Add a clearfix or float it's parent div.

For the clearfix, add the `cf` class to your footer element, and the following in your CSS:

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}


.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

If you want more specific help I would recommend posting your code here along with iPhone screenshots though, there aren't many people willing to click on a shortened URL when they have no idea where it's going.